# Setting shared libraries prefix when compiling

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, ld

I'm trying to compile a program, I need to set a prefix path on shared library path, I try using `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,-dynamic-linker` and what I got from `ldd` was:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff75336000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f19d55b8000)
/pathtolib/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055d3d67e1000)
```

but what I expecting to get was:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff75336000)
libc.so.6 => /pathtolib/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f19d55b8000)
/pathtolib/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055d3d67e1000)
```

I really need to setup this and force program to use non-default path (/**pathtolib**) for all shared libraries.

this is the command I used to compile:

```
gcc list/list.c -o bin/list -Wl,-rpath,/pathtolib -Wl,--dynamic-linker,/pathtolib/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

---

what did I do wrong?!! :|

Comment: Check out this utility called [patchelf](https://nixos.org/patchelf.html). It is used to change dynamic linker & RPATH of ELF binaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-rpath` option does not specify a *prefix* for individual directories in the search path; rather, it specifies a colon-delimited list of *paths*.  The dynamic linker searches these directories first, but it continues on to the rest of the search path if it needs to do.  Thus, if you want the dynamic linker to resolve `libc.so.6` to `/pathtolib/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`, then you must specify not `/pathtolib` but `/pathtolib/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` in your `rpath`.

I am not aware of a link option or ELF header field that would instruct the dynamic linker to do what you seem to be asking: to modify the standard library search path by prefixing each element.  If you want to do something like that, then you probably need to provide your own dynamic linker.

Alternatively, perhaps you want to construct and use a [chroot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) environment instead of of messing with rpaths.  That requires considerably more work to set up, but it would have the effect of allowing you to use a whole different set of libraries.

Comment: Thank you, I know about chroot, but what I exactly want to do is building my own distro with a different directory structure, this is why I need to prefix. I wanna move all:/etc,/lib,/lib64, ... to:/linux/etc,/linux/lib,/linux/lib64, ...
This is why I need to prefix, I thought this is what rpath does.
now I didn't get my answer, what shoul I do?

Comment: @MerajSahebdar, to the best of my knowledge, there is *nothing* that does exactly what you describe. To build your own distro with the layout you like, you'll need to build substantially everything from scratch.  Chroot is not what you want for the final product, but it could be a big piece of getting from here to there.  You could consider reading [Linux from Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/read.html).  Even if you don't follow exactly their recipe, it has a lot of information that you might find useful.